# Firebase React Binding

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm somewhat new to React, and using the re-base library to work with Firebase.

I'm currently trying to render a table, but because of the way my data is structured in firebase, I need to get a list of keys from two locations- the first one being a list of user keys that are a member of a team, and the second being the full user information.

The team node is structured like this: `/teams/team_id/userkeys`, and the user info is stored like this: `/Users/userkey/{email, name, etc.}`

My table consists of two react components: a table component and a row component.

My table component has props `teamid` passed to it, and I'm using re-base's bindToState functionality to get the associated user keys in `componentWillMount()`. Then, I use bindToState again to get the full user node, like so:

```
componentWillMount() {
  this.ref = base.bindToState(`/teams/${this.props.data}/members`, {
  context: this,
  state: 'members',
  asArray: true,
  then() {
   this.secondref = base.bindToState('/Users', {
   context: this,
   state: 'users',
   asArray: true,
   then() {
     let membersKeys = this.state.members.map(function(item) {
       return item.key;
     });
     let usersKeys = this.state.members.map(function(item) {
       return item.key;
     });
     let onlyCorrectMembersKeys = intersection(membersKeys, usersKeys);
     this.setState({
       loading: false
     });
   }
 });
 }
});
}
```

As you can see, I create `membersKeys` and `usersKeys` and then use underscore.js's intersection function to get all the member keys that are in my users node (note: I do this because there are some cases where a user will be a member of a team, but not be under `/Users`).

**The part I'm struggling with is** adding an additional rebase call to create the full members array (ie. the user data from `/Users` for the keys in `onlyCorrectMembersKeys`.

**Edit: I've tried**

```
    let allKeys = [];
      onlyCorrectMembersKeys.forEach(function(element) {
        base.fetch(`/Users/${element}`, {
          asArray: true,
          then(data) {
            allKeys.prototype.concat(data);
          }
        });
      });
```

But I'm receiving the error `Error: REBASE: The options argument must contain a context property of type object. Instead, got undefined`

I'm assuming that's because onlyCorrectMembersKeys hasn't been fully computed yet, but I'm struggling with how to figure out the best way to solve this..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone dealing with this issue as well, I seemed to have found (somewhat) of a solution:

```
     onlyCorrectMembersKeys.map(function(item) {

         base.fetch(`/Users/${item}`, {
           context: this,
           asObject: true,
           then(data) {
             if (data) {
               allKeyss.push({item,data});
               this.setState({allKeys: allKeyss});
             }
             this.setState({loading: false});
           },
          onFailure(err) {
            console.log(err);
            this.setState({loading: false});
          }
         })
       }, this);
     }
```

This works fine, but when `users` and `members` state is updated, it doesn't update the `allkeys` state. I'm sure this is just due to my level of react knowledge, so when I figure that out I'll post the solution.

**Edit**: using listenTo instead of bindToState is the correct approach as bindToState's callback is only fired once.